Continuous determination of the argument

Let $z=x+iy$ be any complex number, then in general the argument of $z$, i.e. $\arg(z)$ is not continuous since it has jumps of $2\pi$. I'm interested in a continuous determination of the argument. I came up with the following definition of the argument which should make it continuous:
$$
\arg(z)=
\begin{cases}
\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+\frac{\pi}{2}(1-\operatorname{sgn}(x)), ~~x\neq0\\
\frac{\pi}{2}\operatorname{sgn}(y),~~x=0,y\neq 0\\
\end{cases}
$$
where $$
\operatorname{sgn}(t)=
\begin{cases}
1, ~~t>0\\
0,~~t=0\\
-1,~~t<0
\end{cases}
$$

Now my question is, is this a continuous determination of the argument or if no could you help me do define the argument continuously and maybe give some reference where to find it?

The argument is continuous as a morphism from $(\mathbb{C}^\times, \times)$ to $(\mathbb{R}/2\pi \mathbb Z,+)$. Here $(\mathbb{R}/2\pi \mathbb Z,+)$ has what we call the quotient topology and is homeomorphic to $\mathbb S$ the unit circle

Can you give me some references where the continuous determination is defined?

I don’t have a reference sorry but the first step would be studying the multiplicative morphism $ z \mapsto \frac{z}{|z|}$ From that you can have an continuous morphism to thé circle

There does not exist a  continuous argument function $\mathbb C^* = \mathbb C \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb R$.
An argument of a non-zero complex number $z$ is a real number $a$ such that $z = \lvert z \rvert e^{ia}$. Since the function $e^{it}$ has period $2\pi$, $z$ has infinitely many arguments $a_k$, $k \in \mathbb Z$, differing by integral multiples of $2\pi$. You are looking for a continuous argument function $\arg : \mathbb C^* = \mathbb C \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb R$ which means that $\arg(z)$ is an argument for $z$ for all $z \in \mathbb C^*$.
Each $z$ has a unique argument $\arg_{pr}(z)$ which is contained in $(-\pi,\pi]$. This is often denoted as the prinicipal argument of $z$. The function $arg_{pr} : \mathbb C^* \to \mathbb R$ is an argument function which is discontinuous at all points of the negative real axis. However, the restriction of $arg_{pr}$ to the sliced plane $\mathbb C_{-1} = \mathbb C \setminus (-\infty,0]$ is continuous.
Now assume that there exists a continuous argument function $\arg : \mathbb C^* = \mathbb C \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb R$.
Then the difference function $d = \arg_{pr} - \arg$ is continuous on $\mathbb C_{-1}$ and takes values in $2\pi\mathbb Z = \{2\pi n \mid n \in \mathbb Z\}$.
We claim that $d$ is constant on $\mathbb C_{-1}$. Let $z \in \mathbb C_{-1}$. The map $u :  [0,1] \to \mathbb C_{-1}, u(t) = (1-t)z + t$, is well-defined [note that $(1-t)z + t \in (-\infty,0]$ requires $t \in (0,1]$, $\operatorname{Im}z = 0$ and $\operatorname{Re}z \le 0$] and continuous. Hence $d \circ u : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ is continuous. By the IVT it takes all values between $d(z) = (d \circ u)(0)$ and $d(1) =(d \circ u)(1)$. But all values of $d$ are integral multiples of $2\pi$, thus the same is true for $d \circ u$ and we conclude that we must have $d(z) = d(1)$.
Since $d$ is constant (with a value $c$), we see that $\arg_{pr}(z) = \arg(z) + c$ for all $z \in \mathbb C_{-1}$. Consider the sequences $z_n = e^{\pi i - i/n}$ and $\bar z_n = e^{-\pi i + i/n}$ in $\mathbb C_{-1}$ which both converge to $-1$. We have $\arg_{pr} (z_n) = \pi - 1/n$ which converges to $\pi$ and $\arg_{pr} (\bar z_n) = -\pi + 1/n$ which converges to $-\pi$. Since $\arg$ is continuous on $\mathbb C^*$ and we get
$$\pi = \lim_{n \to \infty} \arg_{pr} (z_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty}(\arg (z_n) + c) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\arg (z_n) + c = \arg(-1) +c$$
and
$$-\pi = \lim_{n \to \infty} \arg_{pr} (\bar z_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty}(\arg (\bar z_n) + c) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\arg (\bar z_n) + c = \arg(-1) +c .$$
This contradiction proves that no continuous argument function exists on $\mathbb C^*$.
In particular your function is not continuous. Points of discontinuity can be found on the imaginary axis.

thanks a lot but I'm not looking for a continuous argument but for a continuous determination. Is there somehting like this and if yes can you give me some references.

@user123234 What is a continuous determination? Please give a definition.

I don't know what the definition is it is written in a stochastic calculus book of le Gall and I don't know what continuous determination of the argument means.

@user123234 You should not ask a question whose content is unclear to you. But I am quite sure that a determination of the argument (or the complex logarithm, or any other multivalued function) on a subset $U \subset \mathbb C^*$ is a function $\arg$ defined on $U$ which selects, or determines, for each $z \in U$ a specific value $\arg z$ of the argument. This also explains what a  continuous determination is.

See for example https://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~thomas/course_notes/L3_spe_CI_take_home_soln.pdf where you can find  this terminology. Look especially at "1) Let $\varphi$ be a differentiable map from ..." on page 1.
